# Is it secure to use "require" with GET/POST data?

Tags: php, security

Is it secure to use the following code:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . $_GET['page'] . ".php")
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal - @Rok Krajl is right.  This is a classic directory traversal vulnerability.

Comment: Just to "cheer you up", this is really common vurneability :)

Comment: everyone reading this question should give the ArtDesire +1 for caring about security as Rok is right, very common indeed!

Comment: @Mikey1980 I reply Rok why It isn't suitable method for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not secure. You can use array with allowed values.
For example

```
$allowed_pages = array('index', 'test', 'my_page')
if (!in_array($_GET['page'], $allowed_pages)){
    echo 'good bye';
    die();
} else {
   //
}
```

Comment: thanks for idea, but I would like to do directly redirect to pages folder

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not secure. Why?

Because sequence of two dots **/../** means one directory back and the attacker could potentially include anything on your system, even above `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. (In an unfortunate configuration that means secret/sensitive OS config files.)

You have to IF or SWITCH for the allowed values to prevent malicious input. Example:

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
     case 'welcome': $page='welcome';
     case 'shop': $page='shop';
     default: $page='index';
}
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . $page . ".php")
```

Also check out `in_array()` for a little easier filtration.

Comment: I'd recommend hiding the logic in a function, but a *whitelist* is generally a safe approach for various similar situations.

Comment: @pst, It is only a demonstration, for a beginner :)

Comment: I used it before, but now I have too many pages, and want to improve it.

Comment: I tried /../ and some similar sequence, and I got redirect to main page of site.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow has a useful Q&A for how to [sanitize user input with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).  It's a few years old, but the principles haven't changed at all.

The quick answer is: if you can avoid the problem in the first place, you're better off.

Show us how you're trying to use this, and we may be able to offer suggestions for improvement.

Comment: The way I read it, the question was "Is this secure", to which the right answer is "No, never" and a wrong answer is "perhaps, if sanitized".

Comment: it's the same of second way of Mikey1980.

Comment: @ghoti Yes -- that is always "true" -- but the linked question does not talk about this case at all. It's good advice, but needs an expansion to be relevant here ..

Answer (score -1):

If you trust all the files in the pages dir try:

```
if (in_array($_GET['page'],glob("/pages/*.php"))) {
   require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . $_GET['page'] . ".php");
} else echo "Nice try hacker!";
```

Here's another solution using parts of a function I use to clean uploaded filenames:

**OPTION #2** *thanks Daniel, Rok!*

```
$page = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_GET['page']);
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . str_replace("/",'',$page) . ".php";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    require($filename);
} else echo "Nice try hacker!";
```

Note that this will only work if there are no special characters in your file names

Comment: Globing whole directory is slow. It is better to use file_exists() on just the requested file. Your code also has a few bugs.

Comment: your right `file_exists()` is WAY faster when I tested on a huge dir but  honestly with less than 100 files it made no difference, at least on on my box... also fixed the missing `)` and `;`

Comment: Your second example is just as vurneable as the original OP's code. The thing is a little more tricky.

Comment: I didn't understand meaning of first way, but second way is the same I have :D

Comment: I know my edit isn't the most secure but the odds of an attacker knowing where to find PHP scripts on your server are unlikely, for a basic templating system this should suffice

Comment: @Mikey1980: `str_replace` won't work, since the slashes may be escaped.  Check out [the OWASP page linked above](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) for examples.

Comment: To help others I've clean up my entire answer, thanks to Rok and Daniel for all the help.. like the OP I'm hear to learn

Comment: @Mikey1980: I see you've switched from `str_replace` to `preg_replace`, but unless I'm reading it wrong I don't think your regex is correct.  But overall I think you're taking the wrong tack here: the correct approach is to *whitelist* the valid pages, not try to filter out everything that could be harmful (which turns into a game of [walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx) which you are unlikely to win).

Answer (score -3):

use regExp to check your `$_GET['page']`!